# How to add an easing function to increase a variable value during animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, easing-functions

I am looking for some math genius to help me with this one:

I have a quite simple keyframe js animation:

```
var i = 0;
var o = 0; // opacity
var y_frames = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"];   

function draw_y() {

    requestAnimationFrame( draw_y );
    // drawing
    if ( i < y_frames.length ) {  
        $y  .text( y_frames[i] )
            .css( { opacity: o } );
        i++;
        o += 0.03;
    } else {
        // code to be executed when animation finishes
    }
};
draw_y();
```

In addition to stepping the keyframes I add some opacity until it reaches the value 1. This works very well and very smooth. So far so good.
What I would like to add is some easeOutSine to the increment of the opacity value. I know that this is possible by using this function:

```
function easeOutSine(t, b, c, d) {
    return c * Math.sin(t/d * (Math.PI/2)) + b;
}
```

but I need some help how to combine the two. How can I do this?
Anyone who did this before me? Thanks a lot!

Garavani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you combine both functions

```
var i = 0;
var o = 0; // opacity
var y_frames = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H",];   
function draw_y() {
    // drawing
    if ( i < y_frames.length ) { 
        o = easeOutSine( i , 0 , 1, y_frames.length);
        $y  .text( y_frames[i] )
            .css( { opacity: o } );
        i++;
        window.requestAnimationFrame( draw_y );
    } else {
        // code to be executed when animation finishes
    }
};

function easeOutSine(t, b, c, d) {
    return c * Math.sin(t/d * (Math.PI/2)) + b;
}
window.requestAnimationFrame( draw_y );
```

Note: Always call the `requestAnimationFrame` inside the condition or it will keep running infinitely.

Comment: Wow, thank you for this concrete and awesome help! Made me learn something, too. The animation request stuff I learned here: http://creativejs.com/resources/requestanimationframe/  Seems logic what you said, I will keep that in mind. Thanks again!

Comment: Hello Garavani! Glad this code helped you :)
[https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame) I'ld prefer you read from mozilla docs for detailed information.